# Refusal to float right

Tags: html, css

My menu has logo to the left then links beside it, then a dropdown link to the right.. however the dropdown link on the end refuses to float right.

logo ---- link link link link ------------------dropdownlink

```css
#main {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 60px;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #000;
 z-index: 30;
}

#main a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}


.nav {
  display: flex; 
  max-width: 1600px;
}


.right, .left{
  display: inline-block;
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #f0f0ee;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  min-width: 185px;
  right: 0px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e7;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header id="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">        
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">link <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: why should it? You never floated it class right/left just sets a display of inline-block. the only place you have any floats are on the `<li>` tag, and they'll only float within their containing `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css class with `right: 0` and `position:absolute` property

```
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```css
#main {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 60px;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #000;
 z-index: 30;
}

#main a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.right {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex; 
  max-width: 1600px;
}


.right, .left{
  display: inline-block;
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #f0f0ee;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  min-width: 185px;
  right: 0px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e7;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header id="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="nav">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">        
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">link <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then use the class pull-right